# Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

I’m big enthusiast of Manjaro since 2015 but today I got a problem that I couldn’t resolve on my own. After big updates done few days ago (by update manager) I have a problem with compiling Kernel Drivers on kernel 4.15.18-1. After call make I got error:

```
make -C /usr/lib/modules/4.15.18-1-MANJARO/build M=/run/media/mati/common/hello_world modules
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.18-1-MANJARO/build'
**Makefile:974: *** "Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel". Stop.**
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.18-1-MANJARO/build'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Błąd 2
```

The problem is that I cannot install mentioned libraries and command: **pacman -Q libelf**
returns
**libelf 0.170-1**

i have no idea what happend, I tried another kernels (I have few versions installed) but each has problems (e.g. the newest, experimental 4.17 has problem with asm goto of gcc compiler). I started learning Linux Kernel Drivers programming but now I can’t learn because of these compilation problems … anyone can help me ?

(Hope my english is understanable).

Greetings !

Comment: crossposted: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-generate-orc-metadata-for-config-unwinder-orc-y/46827/35

Answer (score 8):

I got this error while setting up VirtualBox in my Fedora OS 29, I issued the following command and this issue got resolved.

```
sudo dnf install elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Comment: this doesn't apply to the OP's question (manjaro != fedora), however I experienced the same thing on Fedora 29

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to install these packages on your system?

```
elfutils
elfutils-libelf-devel
libelf-dev
libelf-devel
```

May require dependencies such as: `zlib-devel`

Comment: For CentOS7, this was: `elfutils-devel`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to install elfutils-devel first then install eflutils and eflutils-libelf-devel. libelf-dev and libelf-devel could not be found but when I ran /sbin/vboxconfig again this time it did not error out. I ran the check, "systemctl status vboxdrv" and this time it showed Active: as Active (exited) and I was able to spin up the VM.